# how do I listen to an mp3 I uploaded to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mp3, streaming

I don't have an Ubuntu One mp3 music streaming account, which I am assuming is necessary for streaming mp3s that you purchase from the Ubuntu store. But what about my personal mp3s I have on my computer and have uploaded to the free 5gig ubuntu one service?

I have uploaded an mp3 to a folder in my Ubuntu One auto sync folder on my Ubuntu Precise computer.

I want to listen to that mp3 using my iphone 4 with ios 5 and the ubuntu one app.

Unfortunately for Ubuntu, it looks like I have to download the mp3 through the ubuntu app and then send it to Dropbox (their competition) in order to listen to it.

How can I just listen to the mp3 I uploaded (not bought from ubuntu) on my iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a music streaming account it should just work: all the music in your account that is in supported formats should appear in the music streaming app on your phone. This does not include music that is in folders that have been shared with you. It's possible your music is appearing under "Unknown Artist", if we've had problems reading the metadata from it. Other than that, it should just be there. Please contact support if it isn't there (or if it's "Unknown", really).

If you don't have a streaming subscription, you can't stream music.

Comment: Thank you. The answe is, you need a strewing account even if you want to stream your own Ubuntu one unrelated private content. That's lame. Totally lame. I can understand a streaming account to stream Ubuntu one music or streaming content but my private files that I uploaded should be downloadable to my device at least

Comment: The streaming service is currently a premium service. However, on both android and iOS you can use the Ubuntu One Files app to download the music to your device and then listen to it.